# Error starting activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app that contains an alarm. When the alarm triggers it should start a new activity, but it only shows 'Unfortunately application has stopped'.

Even the doesn't say anything.
Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.provider.Settings;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Intent i = new Intent(arg0, aani.class);
        arg0.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post error log

Comment: The thing is there is no log

Comment: @OAJJ its a crash there must be crash log associated

Comment: I use android studio but nothing appears to the log. Do I have to change something there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to add the flag to create a new task:

```
Intent i = new Intent(arg0, aani.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
arg0.startActivity(i);
```